# Why does Resharper’s Alt + Enter doesn’t work in VS2015 when trying to create a new method?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I am using version 9.0 (can't upgrade to newer version than this) of Resharper  and when I try to use it in VS2015, the Alt+Enter features doesn’t work in specific scenarios. For instance when I try to create a new method it doesn’t work, but works for other scenarios like when cursor is on a variable and R# suggests changing it to const. I have tried enabling/resetting as other posts have suggested but no luck so far. In my case, it’s not as if Alt+Enter is not working, but it is not working only on specific cases.

Please see screenshot below:[image: Not Working]
[image: Working]

Comment: Have you enabled all in R# `Options -> Code Editing -> Context Actions`?

Comment: yep, all the options were enabled. Just for the heck of it I downloaded the trial of the latest version and it is working fine. So, I will assume my issue was on the version I had, but at some point later it was fixed. Too bad my subscription expired before the new fix rolled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2015 and R# v9.0. Then I updated R# to v10.0.2. Finnaly it worked.

Comment: Yes, that was the fix for me as well.